# problem deleting document Vuejs Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I am creating site for my store and learning Vue js at the same time. I'm having a problem with delete product using id. I'm using Vue js 3 and Firebase 9.

I have this on main.j

```
const dataBase = collection(db, "products");
```

and this on products.js

```
import { dataBase } from '../main';
import { addDoc, deleteDoc, onSnapshot, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

export default {
  name: "Products",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      product: {
        name: '',,
        price: '',
        brand: '',
        category: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveData() {
      try {
        addDoc(dataBase, this.product).then((docRef) => {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
      }
    },
    deleteProduct(doc) {
      if (confirm('Видалити ?')) {
        deleteDoc(doc(dataBase, "products", docRef.id));
      } else {

      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    onSnapshot(dataBase, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        this.products.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      })
    });
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is really hard to help without more debugging information. I recommend setting a breakpoint on each line, running the code in the debugger, and then checking the value of each variable on each line it hits. When you do that: what is the first line where a variable has a different value from what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a typo issue, instead of `docRef.id` you need right `doc.id`

```
deleteProduct(doc) {
  if (confirm('Видалити ?')) {
    deleteDoc(doc(dataBase, "products", doc.id));
  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. Thank you anyway